# Binary Search Tree Deletion Issue

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

The program is running well in for the other method. However in my deletion, espeacially in one case that when i'm going to delete  a node which has 2  children i  can get to perform the transplant part but no matter what i tried i could not get rid of the right child which i just replaced with the its  parents.

i have tried  to set it to null and return  it right away  when it set to null(which  it should be  deleted)

the print methods are working perfectly fine but not the  deletion one.

this is my output:

```
INSERT 4 E 3 E 6 E 2 H 1 T 5 Y 7 S
POSTORDER
THEYSEE
INORDER
THEEYES
DELETE 6 4 1 2
PREORDER
YESS
EXIT
```

so the problem now is why the hell the key 7 get duplicated it never get to deleted while i'm trying to  move its data  from 7 to 6.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean done = false;
        BinarySearchTree myTree = new BinarySearchTree();

        while (!done && s.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = s.nextLine();
            Scanner ls = new Scanner(line);
            String token = ls.next();
            switch (token.toUpperCase()) {

                case "INSERT":
                    while(ls.hasNext()) {
                        myTree.insert(Integer.parseInt(ls.next()), ls.next());
                    }

                    continue;
                case "INORDER":
                    myTree.inorderSearch();
                    System.out.println();
                    continue;

                case "DELETE":
                    while(ls.hasNext()) {
                        myTree.deleteNode(myTree.root,Integer.parseInt(ls.next()));
                    }
                    continue;

                case "PREORDER":
                    myTree.preorder();
                    System.out.println();
                    continue;
                case "POSTORDER":
                    myTree.postorder();
                    System.out.println();
                    continue;
                case "EXIT":
                    done = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
//BINARY SEARCH TREE CLASS

class BinarySearchTree {

    class Node {
        int key;
        String data;
        Node  right, left;

        public Node(int item, String data) {
            this.key = item;
            this.data = data;
            this.left = this.right = null;
        }

        public void setKey(int key) {
            this.key = key;
        }

        public void setData(String data) {
            this.data = data;
        }

        public void setRight(Node right) {
            this.right = right;
        }

        public void setLeft(Node left) {
            this.left = left;
        }

        public Node getRight() {
            return right;
        }

        public Node getLeft() {
            return left;
        }

        public int getKey() {
            return key;
        }

        public String getData() {
            return data;
        }
    }

    Node root;


    BinarySearchTree() {
        this.root = null;
    }

    private Node insertHelper(Node root, int key, String data) {

        if (root == null) {
            root = new Node( key, data);
            return root;
        }

        if (key < root.key)
            root.left = insertHelper(root.left, key, data);
        else if (key > root.key)
            root.right = insertHelper(root.right, key, data);

        return root;
    }


    void insert(int key, String data) {
        root = insertHelper(root, key, data);
    }

    void inorderSearch() {
        inorderSearchHelper(root);
    }

    private void inorderSearchHelper(Node root) {
        if (root != null) {
            inorderSearchHelper(root.left);
            System.out.print(root.data);
            inorderSearchHelper(root.right);
        }
    }

    public void postorder(){
        postorderHelper(root);
    }

    private void postorderHelper(Node root) {
        if (root == null)
            return;

        postorderHelper(root.left);
        postorderHelper(root.right);
        System.out.print(root.data);
    }

    public void preorder(){
        preorderHelper(root);
    }

    private void preorderHelper(Node node) {
        if (node == null)
            return;

        System.out.print(node.data);
        preorderHelper(node.left);
        preorderHelper(node.right);
    }
    // DELETE FKING NODEs!

    /*private void transplant(Node root,Node u, Node v){
        if(u. == )
    }*/

    public static Node minimumElement(Node root) {
        if (root.left == null)
            return root;
        else {
            return minimumElement(root.left);
        }
    }

    public static Node deleteNode(Node root, int key) {
        if (root == null)
            return null;
        if (root.key > key) {
            root.left = deleteNode(root.left, key);
        } else if (root.key < key) {
            root.right = deleteNode(root.right, key);
        } else {
            // if nodeToBeDeleted have both children
            if (root.left != null && root.right != null) {
                Node temp = root;
                // Finding minimum element from right
                Node minNodeForRight = minimumElement(temp.right);
                // Replacing current node with minimum node from right subtree
                root.data = minNodeForRight.data;
                // Deleting minimum node from right now
                deleteNode(root.right, minNodeForRight.key);
            }
            // if nodeToBeDeleted has only left child
            else if (root.left != null) {
                root = root.left;
            }
            // if nodeToBeDeleted has only right child
            else if (root.right != null) {
                root = root.right;
            }
            // if nodeToBeDeleted do not have child (Leaf node)
            else
                root = null;
        }
        return root;
    }
}
```

so this is the right output:

```
INSERT 4 E 3 E 6 E 2 H 1 T 5 Y 7 S
POSTORDER
THEYSEE
INORDER
THEEYES
DELETE 6 4 1 2
PREORDER
YES
EXIT
```

Comment: I think you should explain a bit more what you want do with that code. It takes a lot of time to guess your intentions and even than it's only a guess.

Comment: Did you try debugging? It will answer your question. Hint: if you take a look at `insertHelper`, you will see a certain pattern. You can also notice the same pattern in `deleteNode`. But in one line in `deleteNode` you forgot to use this pattern.

Comment: What happens if the key is found on a node which has two children, and the minimum right sub key is on the immediate right child?